# serialize write-only field which is not present in django model using viewset

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using a django viewset and I want to serialize a field which is not in the model.
it is an extra field that would be passed by the user.

```
class Bank(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    
    objects = models.Manager()
```

```
class BankSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    name = serializer.CharField()
    documents = serializers.ListField(write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Bank
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'documents']
    def create(self,  validated_data):
        print(validated_data.get('documents'))
```

```
class BankViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = BankSerializer
```

I am using a **modelViewset** for my view.

**However** I noticed that after I serialize, the documents field is missing

Comment: Where are you expecting to see the documents field? Can you add your code where you are looking for and not finding the field?

Comment: I have updated the serializer to show where i was checking for the data.

Comment: can you show us your post request payload?